# Java thread not working in view

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a simple login window in JavaFX. When the user inserts his username and password I want to make a simple string "progress bar" in another thread while the main thread processes the inputs.

When the main thread gets to the if statement (let's say the passwords don't match) I want the progress to stop when the alert is thrown. But with this code it continues even after the alert is thrown.

```
public void validateLogin(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(loading_txt.getText().length() < 10)loading_txt.setText(loading_txt.getText() + "|");
            else loading_txt.setText("|");
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    String username = username_field.getText();
    String password = password_field.getText();

    if (!(BCrypt.checkpw(password_field.getText(), dbHandler.getLoginByUsername(username_field.getText()).getPassword()))) {
        throwAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Login problem", "Password doesn't match.", "Wrong password. Please, check out and try it again. ");
        thread.join();
        return;
    }

    thread.join();
    //other code
}
```

So I made a little change in the if statement and put the thread.join() before the alert. Now the progress can't be even seen.

```
    if (!(BCrypt.checkpw(password_field.getText(), dbHandler.getLoginByUsername(username_field.getText()).getPassword()))) {
        thread.join();
        throwAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Login problem", "Password doesn't match.", "Wrong password. Please, check out and try it again. ");
        return;
    }
```

How does this little change cause the progress to be seen or not to be seen? What do I have to change to stop the progressing when the alert is thrown? Could it be caused by some functionality in JavaFX?

Comment: You state that the "thread is not working", but you're not using a separate thread, not when you have `thread.join();` in your code. You want to use a listener / notification set up instead.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought the thread.start() was enough to make a separate thread. Not a word about listeners or notification in my school materials though. I'll do some googling. Thank you!

Comment: Oh yes, it creates and starts a separate thread, but you immediately squash that thread with your call to `join();`.

Comment: In `JavaFX` if you want to achieve such a task, use `Task` for Calculation, and `Platform.runLater(Runnable runnable)` for Updating Progress Bar!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well that's what I want to do. It is supposed to be just a short thread that is making the progress while dbHandler gets data from database.

Comment: @Yahya Thanks for the tip, I'll try that!

Comment: You don't yet understand how threads work I'm afraid. Please understand that your current code is squashing (combining) the threads *immediately* before the background thread has had a chance to do any work, and this risks blocking your GUI's thread. Again, you will want to *notify* the GUI when the background worker has changed state.

Comment: @TomášZajda I'll try to make an example on my IDE

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It was actually blocking the GUI thread, I think I see the problem now. This is my first code with threads, so thanks for patience.

Comment: @Yahya That would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an **Example**, you may take the idea and apply it to your program (*Explanation in comments*).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;

public class ProgressBarExample extends Application{

    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(); // your progress bar


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // The structure and components are for example only
        TextField password = new TextField();
        Button test = new Button("Test");
        HBox container = new HBox();
        container.getChildren().addAll(password, test);
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(container);


        // add action listener to the button
        test.setOnAction(e->{
            // when it's pressed add Progress bar and other stuff that are concerned with the GUI! 
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){ // always use this to update GUI components
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    root.getChildren().add(pb);
                    // you can add label to the root...etc
                    // or update your progress bar ..etc
                    // in a nutshell: anything needs to be updated in GUI.
                }
            });

            Task<Boolean> validatePassword = new Task<Boolean>(){ // always use Task to do complex-long calculations
                @Override
                protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
                    return validatePassword(password);  // method to validate password (see later)      
                }
            };

            validatePassword.setOnSucceeded(ee->{ // when Task finishes successfully
                System.out.println("Finished");
                root.getChildren().remove(pb); // remove the progress bar   
                if(!validatePassword.getValue()){
                  Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Wrong Password", ButtonType.OK);
                  alert.showAndWait();
                }
            });

            validatePassword.setOnFailed(eee->{ // if it fails
                 System.out.println("Failed");
                 root.getChildren().remove(pb); // remove it anyway                                 
            });

            new Thread(validatePassword).start(); // add the task to a thread and start it
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    // validate here in this method
    public static boolean validatePassword(TextField password){
        for(int i=0; i<99999; i++){ // suppose it is a long process
            System.out.println("Processing");
        }
        if(password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Invalid")){ // suppose it's invalid, just for testing
            return false
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }   
}
```

**Test:**

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: @Tomáš Zajda Please copy-paste the above-code to your IDE and test it yourself.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! I think I see how it works now.